# UTF8 compatibility

Tags: java, utf-8, ftp

I am using a function to upload one file to my server by FTP. Here is my code and works fine but the file example.json that creates is not UTF8 compatible because it has AtlÃ©tico instead Atlético for example. Somebody can tell me how correct this? Thanks

```
public static void subir(){
        String server = myserver;
        int port = 21;
        String user = mouser;
        String pass = mypass;

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {

            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            // Uploads first file using an InputStream
            File firstLocalFile = new File("example.json");

            String firstRemoteFile = "MyDir/example.json";
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(firstLocalFile);

            System.out.println("Subiendo archivo a servidor...");
            boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile(firstRemoteFile, inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            if (done) {
                System.out.println("Subido perfectamente");
            }


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

And to save my file I use

```
public static void guardar(){
        FileOutputStream fop = null;
        File file;
        String content = sBuffer.toString();

        try {

            file = new File("example.json");
            fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            else{
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            // get the content in bytes
            byte[] contentInBytes = content.getBytes();

            fop.write(contentInBytes);
            fop.flush();
            fop.close();

            System.out.println("Archivo guardado");
            subir();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fop != null) {
                    fop.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you writing contents to the file? Which class are you using to write data in your file?

Comment: And how are you then *reading* the file to see AtlÃ©tico?

Comment: I have updated my question with the function that creates and saves the file

Comment: The file looks good, it has Atlético, the problem is in the upload I think

Answer (score 1):

The critical part is the conversion of a `String` into a sequence of `byte`s.

In your case, this is the line

```
byte[] contentInBytes = content.getBytes();
```

When you call `String.getBytes()` it uses the encoding of your locale, which from your observation seems to be something else than `UTF-8`. If you want to use a specific encoding, you need to specify the encoding. You can use

```
byte[] contentInBytes = content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

However, it seems to me that the problem is not how you convert your Java String into UTF-8 but how you interpret the UTF-8 string.

The byte sequence `41 74 6c c3 a9 74 69 63 6f` is

- `AtlÃ©tico` when interpreted as ISO-8859-1
- `Atlético` when interpreted as UTF-8

To me the problem seems to be with the code or program that interprets the converted string, not with the conversion in the Java program (still, if you need it to be UTF-8, fix it so it will not depend on the Locale settings).

By the way, if you want to save text (not binary data) to a file, you might want to go for `Writer` instead of `OutputStream`. The following method demonstrates how to write a String into a file using `UTF-8`.

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public static void save(final File file, final String text) throws IOException {
    try (final OutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
        final Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fout, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    ) {
        out.write(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it says that StandardCharsets can not be resolved to a variable

Comment: What Java version do you use? `StandardCharsets` was added in Java 7. Did you `import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets`?

Comment: I am using java 6, there is not another way to do this?

Comment: Why are you using Java 6? Java 6 is end-of-life. People shouldn't be using it any longer. See [Oracle Java SE Support Roadmap](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html). You could also use `"UTF-8"` instead of `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`. Just check out the [documentation of `OutputStreamWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html).

Comment: Thanks, I have changed to Java 7 and I have changed my code to yours but when I open the file I still watching AtlÃ©tico :(

Comment: And I don´t know why because in my saved file Atlético looks fine but when I upload to my server looks bad AtlÃ©tico